# github-pages 200.html support

Tags: github-pages

Does github pages support the 200.html file? The intended functionality is that it catches any requests for files that do not exist in the website and responds with its content and a HTTP 200 status. I couldn't find any doco on it.

I know they support [404.html](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be supported yet, and is discussed as part of [isaacs/github issue 408](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/408), a non-official feature requests to GitHub.

Using [`400.html` instead was a "hack" seen in 2016](https://twitter.com/csuwildcat/status/730558238458937344?lang=en).

Comment: The 404.html is terrible for SEO though. Its better just to use it to redirect back to index.html. Anyway cheers - looks like 200.html is not supported.